# How do I make the b43 kernel module load on boot in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, broadcom

## Background

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop from 2008, which has a Broadcom wireless chip. I have previously successfully used Ubuntu/Kubuntu on it by installing the `firmware-b43-installer` package, certainly on 14.04, I can't recall if I've installed 16.04 before on this laptop.

Recently, I installed Ubuntu 16.04, and installed `firmware-b43-installer` as before. Running `sudo modprobe b43` makes the wireless work, but this does not persist after reboot.

The `b43` module is blacklisted by `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf`, which is autogenerated by `bcmwl-kernel-source`. This blacklisting doesn't stop `sudo modprobe b43` from working - it loads the module anyway and WiFi then works until reboot.

## What I've tried

1. Adding `b43`, preceeded by its dependencies, in `/etc/modules`, running `sudo update-initramfs -u`, and rebooting. The module does not get loaded.
2. Adding `b43`, preceeded by its dependencies, in `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`, running `sudo update-initramfs -u`, and rebooting. The module does not get loaded.
3. Adding `b43`, preceeded by its dependencies, in both `/etc/modules` and `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`, running `sudo update-initramfs -u`, and rebooting. The module does not get loaded.
4. Uninstalling `bcmwl-kernel-source` in order to remove `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf`, in combination with 1, 2, and 3 above. The module does not get loaded, and running `sudo modprobe b43` manually no longer works, so I presume that the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package is necessary for `b43` to work, despite the fact that `bcmwl-kernel-source` blacklists `b43`.
5. Leaving `bcmwl-kernel-source` installed, but manually deleting `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf`, in combination with 1, 2, and 3 above. The module does not get loaded, but running `sudo modprobe b43` manually once booted works.
6. Adding a script to root's crontab on `@reboot` that loops running `modprobe b43` until `lsmod` indicates that it is loaded. The script runs, and keeps running indefinitely, but the module never gets loaded, despite the fact that the script works when run manually from a terminal once booted.

Comment: @MichaelBay So far as I can tell, all the answers there are related to getting it working in the first place, which I have already done, indeed in the same way as that answer. Keeping it working post-reboot is the problem I have, which is a problem others in that thread don't seem to be having in the first place.

Comment: Please read carefully and follow **all** the instructions specific for your Broadcom chipset.

Comment: I have now done so; the module still doesn't load post-reboot. One thing I noticed when reading through was that Luis Alvarado's answer appears to assume than neither `bcmwl-kernel-source` nor `firmware-b43-installer` is installed by default, which was not the case for me; `bcmwl-kernel-source` was already installed on a clean install of 16.04.3.

Comment: The guide also tells you to uninstall `bcmwl-kernel-source` if you need `b43`, before installing `firmware-b43-installer`. Also mentions that in same cases *after installing the firmware-b43-installer you need to remove the b43 module, enable it again and even proceed to unblock with rfkill*.

Comment: Ah, some of the later answers do; the main answer by Luis Alvarado does not say to uninstall `bcmwl-kernel-source` if you need `b43`, it only says to uninstall `bcmwl-kernel-source` if you had already manually installed it, which I had not. Also, I had already discovered that uninstalling `bcmwl-kernel-source` broke `b43` for me (despite the fact that they are supposed to be incompatible...)

Comment: Also here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110 . It doesn't matter how `bcmwl-kernel-source` was installed (it probably was via Additional Drivers). What matters is if it's there it needs to be uninstalled/purged.

Answer (score 0):

So, moving my script that called `modprobe b43` until `lsmod` indicates that it is loaded from being called by root's crontab to being called by `/etc/rc.local` fixed this for me. Why this makes any difference I have no idea though.

Comment: Sounds like b43 and ssb are blacklisted in another file in /etc/modprobe.d

Comment: Check `grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*`